# I have the formula I want to use but now sure how to change it with time another time zone

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp, time-zone

I have a formula setup that I want to use. But I have a separate sheet that I want to use in a different time zone. The one I have written is in `EST`. but I want another sheet to use the same formula but in `CDT`.

---

I am using this in Google Sheets. I am using it to have a static date and time change with a click on another cell.

```
function TIMESTAMP() {
var today = new Date();
var date = (today.getMonth()+1)+'/'+today.getDate()+'/'+today.getFullYear();
var Time = today.getHours(HH)+":" + today.getMinutes(mm) + ":" + today.getSeconds(ss);
var dateTime = date+' '+Time;
return dateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, sec))` to format a Date as you want it to be and delay it manually. (Ex. GMT +02, EST +.., ecc..)

Or you can use `new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "substitute with the timeZone you need"})` to use the TimeZone that you want. NOTICE! This doesn't work on every browser and i don't know if it works on Google Sheet. Anyway this method is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54453990/11574313